# fail to list directory using plink

Tags: perl, ssh, putty

I have a perl script which I use to list the files from remote server using plink.exe. The script was working fine unless the admin changed the password yesterday. Now with new password, my script is not working. Password is correct because I can connect using Filezilla/putty.

I can login using putty with SSH as well.

The code I am trying is

```
plink.exe -pw password -ssh -l username server_IP ls -1 /home/path/to/folder/
```

The error I am getting is

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The path is correct, checked multiple times (moreover no change in code, which was working till yesterday. Folders are not deleted as well.)
Can anybody please help?

Comment: I would suspect that within your Perl script, the password may be followed by a whitespace or `\n` or whatever. What you could try is, to replace the line in your script that calls the command with a line that prints it and then copy and paste the password from that output to see if it really works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using full path tto ls and qutoing the command?

```
plink.exe -pw password -ssh -l username server_IP "/bin/ls/ls -1 /home/path/to/folder/"
```